# android studio create activity and use it without show it

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

I have 2 activities:
1. ListActivity
2. MainActivity

in Listactivity I got ListView and:

```
static ArrayList<String> list;
static ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
```

in MainActivity i have a button which i want to add element to the ListActivity's list when i press it, but i want that the MainActivity will be the launcher.

i tried somthing like this:

MainActivity

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ListActivity.list.add("test");
    ListActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the program is crushed probably because the method OnCreate of ListActivity was not called.

is there any way to create an activity from another one?

is there any better way to achive my goal?

Comment: I think you need to call methods of that activity not the complete activity,Activity means a view which has a layout,so ignoring the view you have only code left behind

Comment: but i cant access like that to the list and the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Activities should be independent. You should not be calling the ListActivity variables directly from MainActivity onClick method

Instead, pass the data through the bundle and receive the data in ListActivity
Pass the data and update the adapter